# How create extension function ifNullOrEmpty?

Tags: kotlin, extension-methods

I want to create a function like ifEmpty() of Kotlin that will also check for null:

```
ifNullOrEmpty{
  //some code if null or empty
}
```

How can i do this?

And does anyone know what the code below is called?

```
: R where C : CharSequence, C : R
```

Example of Kotlin ifEmpty() function.

```
@SinceKotlin("1.3")
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun <C, R> C.ifEmpty(defaultValue: () -> R): R where C : CharSequence, C : R =
    if (isEmpty()) defaultValue() else this
```

Thanks and have a nice day!

Comment: In theory just replacing `isEmpty()` by `isNullOrEmpty()` should work, but I see that somehow copying the existing function gives error on the `CharSequence` part for me

Comment: @IvoBeckers This function returns boolean, I need the extension to return a function.
You talk about **IS**NullOrEmpty, I need **IF**NullOfEmpty. Like `String.IfEmpty{ /*some code*/}`.

Comment: @PavelMaltsev, he's actually suggesting using the current implementation of `ifEmpty` and replace *inside the body* the `isEmpty()` by `isNullOrEmpty()`. What do you have trouble with exactly in doing this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe creating a function exactly as `ifEmpty` is currently not possible without `InlineOnly` and `InlineOnly` is internal. You can hack this out if you want ;-)

Comment: @Joffrey We can't call `IfEmpty` on null and if I will use null-safety code will not so clear

Comment: You would just need to make the receiver nullable, that's not the main issue. Your problem is about using generics in the same way as `ifEmpty`, which is not possible due to what broot pointed out. But you can do with less generics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in other answers, you can't create `ifNullOrEmpty()` with similar generic logic as in `ifNull()`, because you need `@InlineOnly` which is currently internal and can be used by stdlib only.

If you don't mind using internal components and writing code that is potentially not forward-compatible, you can utilize a small hack:

```kotlin
@Suppress("INVISIBLE_REFERENCE", "INVISIBLE_MEMBER")
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun <C, R> C.ifNullOrEmpty(defaultValue: () -> R): R where C : CharSequence, C : R =
    if (isNullOrEmpty()) defaultValue() else this
```

Alternatively, you can use "less generic" implementation as provided by @Joffrey, which should be sufficient for most use cases.

Answer (score 3):

> does anyone know what the code below is called?

You are mixing 2 pieces in your snippet:

- `: R` is simply the return type of the function
- `where C : CharSequence, C : R` is called a [`where` clause](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#upper-bounds). Its purpose is to specify multiple upper bounds on the type parameters of the function.

> How can i do this?

Regarding the implementation itself, you may not be able to use as many generics as the original `ifEmpty` (due to `@InlineOnly` being internal), but you can do a simpler version if this is enough for you:

```kotlin
inline fun <R : CharSequence> R?.ifNullOrEmpty(defaultValue: () -> R): R =
    if (isNullOrEmpty()) defaultValue() else this
```

The difference with the stdlib's `ifEmpty` is that the lambda in this case cannot widen the type (you can't return a `CharSequence` from the lambda if you called `ifNullOrEmpty` on a `String`), but this should rarely be needed.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly I don't fully understand why the generic types are necessary in the original `ifEmpty` but I think you can just do it like this:

```
inline fun CharSequence?.ifNullOrEmpty(defaultValue: () -> CharSequence): CharSequence =
    if (isNullOrEmpty()) defaultValue() else this
```

Comment: Generics are there so you can return a type different than `CharSequence`. But this is probably a rather rare case.

Comment: Actually I believe it's very common to use `ifEmpty` on `String` and expect a `String` back, so it's quite important. What is rare (IMO) is to actually widen the type like `ifEmpty` allows, e.g. calling `ifEmpty` on a `String` but returning a `CharSequence` from the lambda.

Comment: I was thinking about cases like e.g. base type `Data` and its subtype `SringData`. If it's empty, you can return another type of `Data` and the result is still `Data`. But then I realized much more common example: `String.ifEmpty { null }`. It also widens `String` into `String?`. This is not needed for `ifNullOrEmpty()`, but for `ifEmpty()` it is super useful.

Comment: Oh yeah I didn't think of the `ifEmpty { null }` case, which I actually did use myself in some projects :D In any case, there is no doubt it is useful to have in the stdlib function, but maybe in a user-defined function like `ifNullOrEmpty()` it can be omitted